# Any native methods to have Firefox display site source code ("View Page Source") in a dark theme (white on black)?

Tags: firefox, themes, source-code, viewer, usability

Does Firefox currently have a native way (perhaps an about:config preference) to display the source code viewer ("View Page Source", `view-source:`) in a dark theme (white on black)?

I performed a search, but didn't see anything relevant.

Before implementing it with userContent.css, I thought it's best to ask.

Comment: It seems that extensions have no access to the page: https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/issues/4149#issuecomment-729042977

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you, I hope it's what you're looking for :

https://github.com/overdodactyl/ShadowFox

Comment: No commits since 2019.